# Merge, output items of both arrays and highlight their respective items

Tags: php

I have two arrays

```
$array1 = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth');
$array2 = array('first', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth');
```

These 2 arrays have items in common, and some of the items are only available on `array1` or `array2`.

What I want to do is to create a table with 2 columns, array1 and array2 as below:

```
array1 ----------- array2
first ----------- first
second ----------- second
third ----------- third
fourth ----------- fourth
fifth ----------- fifth
sixth ----------- sixth
```

but the purpose here is to bold the items found for each column in their respective array.

So for `array1` the `first, second, third, fourth` will be bold, while in `array2` the `first, third, fourth, fifth, sixth` will be bold.

I am messing with `array_diff` and `array_merge` but unfortunately I hit a dead end. I guess it has to be a `foreach` but I can not find the differences.

Any help please?

Comment: Why `second` is placed in second row in table while knowing `third` in second array has the same index as `second` in first array.

Comment: @revo what I am thinking is to create a merged output of both arrays, maybe my output in the question is wrong...

Comment: So the order doesn't necessarily matter?

Comment: @revo yes, the order doesn't necessarily matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points here:

1. Create a unique array from all values
2. If value exists in an array output bolded format otherwise output it as is:

```
$arrayOne = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth');
$arrayTwo = array('first', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth');
// create a unique list
$uniqueValues = array_unique(array_merge($arrayOne, $arrayTwo));
// iterate over and echo a bold or normal value
foreach ($uniqueValues as $value) {
    echo in_array($value, $arrayOne) ? "**$value**" : $value, ' - ';
    echo in_array($value, $arrayTwo) ? "**$value**" : $value, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
**first** - **first**
**second** - second
**third** - **third**
**fourth** - **fourth**
fifth - **fifth**
sixth - **sixth**
```

Answer (score 2):

A combination of `array_unique(array_merge())` will give you every value that exists in either array.

```
$array = array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2));
```

Loop through this result checking each value's presence in the appropriate array, as you output your table.

Assuming example CSS:

```
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Try this PHP:

```
echo "<table>\n";
echo "<tr><th>array1</th><th>array2</th></tr>\n";
foreach( $array as $value ){
    $class1 = in_array($value, $array1)?"bold":"";
    $class2 = in_array($value, $array2)?"bold":"";
    echo "<tr><td class='$class1'>$value</td><td class='$class2'>$value</td></tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

This will output the html in the following snippet:

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>array1</th><th>array2</th></tr>
<tr><td class='bold'>first</td><td class='bold'>first</td></tr>
<tr><td class='bold'>second</td><td class=''>second</td></tr>
<tr><td class='bold'>third</td><td class='bold'>third</td></tr>
<tr><td class='bold'>fourth</td><td class='bold'>fourth</td></tr>
<tr><td class=''>fifth</td><td class='bold'>fifth</td></tr>
<tr><td class=''>sixth</td><td class='bold'>sixth</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to merge both arrays to one big, with all values, then crawl through it.

Merging arrays should be done with `array_merge` or simple `+` operation

In my solution is used inline condition, if is value in first array, append it to bolt element, else, just echo the value.

Also, don't forget to put this output into `table` element

```
<?php
$array1 = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth');
$array2 = array('first', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth');

$merged = $array1 + $array2;
foreach($merged as $value){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.(in_array($value, $array1)? '<b>'.$value.'</b>' : $value).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.(in_array($value, $array2)? '<b>'.$value.'</b>' : $value).'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think this is an answer. The reason for this is that even the 2nd column for array2 takes into consideration the items on array1, the array1 does not take into consideration the items of array2. So, if an item appears only in array2 then the array1 must show it without bold.

Comment: I've run this code, and result was, like your description:
**first** **first**
**second** second
**third** **third**
**fourth** **fourth**
sixth **sixth**

Answer (score 1):

> Code

```
<?php

$array1 = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth');
$array2 = array('first', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth');



function boldSame(array $one, array $two) : array
{
    $results = [];
    $allItems = array_unique(array_merge($one, $two));

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($allItems as $item) {

        $results[$i]['value'] = $item;

        if (in_array($item, $one) && in_array($item, $two)) {
            $results[$i]['bold'] = true;
        } else {
            $results[$i]['bold'] = false;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    return $results;

}


function makeTable(array $values) : string 
{

    $html = '<table>' . PHP_EOL;

    foreach ($values as $value) {

        $html .= '<tr>' . PHP_EOL;

            $html .= '<td>';
                if ($value['bold']) {
                    $html .= '<strong>';
                    $html .= $value['value'];
                    $html .= '</strong>';

                } else {
                    $html .= $value['value'];
                }

            $html .= '</td>';

            $html .= '<td>';
                if ($value['bold']) {
                    $html .= '<strong>';
                    $html .= $value['value'];
                    $html .= '</strong>';

                } else {
                    $html .= $value['value'];
                }

            $html .= '</td>' . PHP_EOL;

            $html .= '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;

    }

    $html .= '</table>' . PHP_EOL;

    return $html;
}

echo makeTable(boldSame($array1, $array2));
```

> Usage

```
echo makeTable(boldSame($array1, $array2));
```

> result

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>first</strong></td><td><strong>first</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>second</td><td>second</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>third</strong></td><td><strong>third</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>fourth</strong></td><td><strong>fourth</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>fifth</td><td>fifth</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>sixth</td><td>sixth</td>
</tr>
</table>
```